# tcp6 in the output netstat

Tags: tcp, netstat

What does column 'tcp6' mean on output netstat?
Please anyone explain the follow output of netstat:

`tcp6 0 0 dmz.local.net:www 5.140.235.6%14631:49964 ESTABLISHED 21393/apache2`

What does **tcp6** mean?

Comment: tcp6 refers to the TCP/IP version 6 (IPv6) protocol that your apache is using to connect to the external host.

Just tcp would mean that the TCP/IP version 4 (IPv4) that is being used

Comment: tcp6 supports both IPv6 and IPv4 protocols

Comment: Interesting is that _netstat -nN*_ shows ip4 address at tcp6 line. 
`tcp6    0   0 172.2.44.11:36559      210.98.81.140:443`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`tcp6` simply means **TCP** protocol over **IP v6**.

> tcp6 0 0 dmz.local.net:www 5.140.235.6%14631:49964 ESTABLISHED 21393/apache2

As from the [netstat manual](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat):

- `tcp6`: The protocol used. Here it is **TCP** over **IPv6**
- `0`: The count of bytes not copied by the user program connected to this socket.
- `0`: The count of bytes not acknowledged by the remote host.
  Local Address
- `dmz.local.net`:**`www`**: Address and port number of the local end of the socket. Unless the  (-n) option is specified, the socket address is resolved to its canonical host name (FQDN), and the port number is translated into the corresponding service name.
- `5.140.235.6%14631`:**`49964`**: Address and port number of the remote end of the socket.
- `ESTABLISHED`: The state of the socket. The state `ESTABLISHED` means the socket has an established connection.
- `21393`/**`apache2`**: Slash-separated pair of the process id (PID) and process name of the process that owns the socket.

To sum up: your **local apache2** process (pid= 21393), listening on the standard www port (**80**) has established a **TCP** (over **IPv6**) connection with the remote host **`5.140.235.6%14631`** on port **49964** (unresolved IPv6 address which is a **link-local** IPv6 address: an address that a computer assigns itself in order to facilitate local communications).

**For more about IPv6**:

- [wikipedia IPv6 address notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)
- [this superuser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/99746/why-is-there-a-percent-sign-in-the-ipv6-address) about % in IPv6, that is *Scope ID*.

Answer (score 1):

It means your `apache2` service is using `IPv6`.

`apache2` will listen on port 80 of your server's IP address.

Answer (score 1):

This means that a connection using TCP/IP version 6 protocol was made and established toward your Apache web server.

TCP/IP version 6 is the follower of TCP/IP version 4.
One of the main difference between the two is the number of IP addresses you can use in IPv6 is far higher of the one allowed by IPv4.

You see also the name and the port at each side of the connection. `dmz.local.net` on port 80 (`www`) beeing your side, the daemon `apache2` running as PID 21393.
The connection is `ESTABLISHED`, meaning that the TCP handshake is successfully accomplished and the client is ready to send information to the server and the server ready to reply the requests from the client.